# PayUMoney Integration in MVC and calling using ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, payumoney

On button click I want the user to redirect to payumoney gateway and if payment has been done successfully, the data of user to be store in database and redirect user to success page vice a versa..

Currently I am saving data using AJAX call and redirect user on ajax success:function.

**AJAX**

```
$('#payNowButton').on("click", function () {

    var total = $('#main_total_s5').html();
    console.log("Total : " + total);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Demo?total=' + total, //Demo method in Home Controller is for payumoney payment gateway.
        type: "POST",
        data: total,
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            window.location.href = result;
            if (result > 0) {
                PlaceOrder(); //after successful payment, it will call this function to save data in database.
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Sucess", "Home")';
            }
            else {
                alert("Some error occurred." + result);
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Failure", "Home")';
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Demo(OrderCustom orderCustom)
    {
        string firstName = "";
        string amount = "";
        string productInfo = "";
        string email = "";
        string phone = "";
        string surl;
        string furl;


        RemotePost myremotepost = new RemotePost();
        string key = "";
        string salt = "";

        //posting all the parameters required for integration.

        myremotepost.Url = "https://secure.payu.in/_payment";
        myremotepost.Add("key", "");
        string txnid = Generatetxnid();
        myremotepost.Add("txnid", txnid);
        myremotepost.Add("amount", amount);
        myremotepost.Add("productinfo", productInfo);
        myremotepost.Add("firstname", firstName);
        myremotepost.Add("phone", phone);
        myremotepost.Add("email", email);
        myremotepost.Add("surl", "http://localhost:/Home/Sucess");//Change the success url here depending upon the port number of your local system.
        myremotepost.Add("furl", "http://localhost:/Home/Failure");//Change the failure url here depending upon the port number of your local system.
        myremotepost.Add("service_provider", "payu_paisa");
        string hashString = key + "|" + txnid + "|" + amount + "|" + productInfo + "|" + firstName + "|" + email + "|||||||||||" + salt;
        string hash = Generatehash512(hashString);
        myremotepost.Add("hash", hash);
        myremotepost.Post();
    }

    public class RemotePost
    {
        private System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Inputs = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();


        public string Url = "";
        public string Method = "post";
        public string FormName = "form1";

        public void Add(string name, string value)
        {
            Inputs.Add(name, value);
        }

        public void Post()
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">", FormName));
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >", FormName, Method, Url));
            for (int i = 0; i < Inputs.Keys.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", Inputs.Keys[i], Inputs[Inputs.Keys[i]]));
            }
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

When I click on button it shows this error :
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzfaz.png)

Comment: this can help you, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c42694/integrate-payumoney-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: How are yo doing this? We can only help with code that we can see.

Comment: Added code and error image.. Please help.. stuck in this more than a week.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem yesterday. What I did i, I removed `myremotepost.Add("service_provider", "payu_paisa");` and It worked!.

Also check the URL once, if you are doing it on test server then the URL would be https://test.payu.in/_payment

"Key" and "SALT" value cannot be blank, these values will be shared to you by payumoney itself.

```
 string key = "";
 string salt = "";
```

Comment: @ Vijay Didamani.. Thank you for the help but I already solved this by using some redirection's and it's working great..

Comment: @JayPatel if you found a solution, please add it as answer to your question and accept it, this will help other users.

Comment: @Jay Patel y cant u post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
myremotepost.Add("service_provider", "payu_paisa");
```

This is Mandatory Field, Recently I am contacting with help desk they are asking for some customization. Then it will work